# prevent automatically append a relation when using accessor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Suppose we have a `Product` model like this :

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['picture'];

    public function getPictureAttribute()
    {
        $picture = NULL;
        if (!$this->images->isEmpty()) {
            $picture = $this->images->where('selected', TRUE)->first()->path;
        }
        return $picture;
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

In the other hand there is an `Image` model like this :

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'path', 'imageable_id', 'imageable_type', 'selected'];

    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

As you can see each **product** can have many **images**. one of those images can be **selected** as default and now I want when fetch a `Product`,that be  include a `picture` field that holds `path` of that selected image. for this I appended a `picture`  attribute to `Product` model as an accessor.

But each time I call a specific product for example in `show` controller method like this :

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return $product;
}
```

Result is like this (a `images` property is included automatically ) :

```
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "code": null,
    "created_at": "2017-12-11 12:21:49",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-23 09:38:38",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "picture": "path 2",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title": "salam",
            "path": "path 1",
            "imageable_id": 1,
            "imageable_type": "Modules\\Product\\Entities\\Product",
            "selected": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-01-23 09:38:38",
            "updated_at": "2018-01-23 09:38:38"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "in the name of god",
            "path": "path 2",
            "imageable_id": 1,
            "imageable_type": "Modules\\Product\\Entities\\Product",
            "selected": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-01-23 09:38:38",
            "updated_at": "2018-01-23 09:38:38"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Updataed Title"
}
```

I don't know what is problem and how can I solve that.

Comment: You don't want `images` included in your result, is that the problem? Put it in the `$hidden` array property of `Product` if thats the case. `protected $hidden = ['images'];`

Comment: Alternatively, manually set your eager loaded relations using `setEagerLoads` method on the model. https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_setEagerLoads

Comment: Is `getPictureAttribute` working??

Comment: yes. This solution had come to my mind , but why this included automatically?

Comment: Yes it is working clearly in the result json he posted.

Comment: @A.B.Developer I think it's automatically loaded due to calling `$this->images` in your accessor method. That loads the polymorphic relation and is thereby in your result.

Comment: @A.B.Developer you can use `unset()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)-

```
 public function getPictureAttribute()
{
    $picture = NULL;
    if (!$this->images->isEmpty()) {
        $picture = $this->images->where('selected', TRUE)->first()->path;
    }
    unset($this->images);
    return $picture;
}
```

`unset` your `key` before returning.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the images relationship being shown is because it's part of the Model attributes once you retrieve it within the picture accessor.

One of the better practices in my opinion is using transformers which control the data shown in the api response. [League fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) offers such functionality. What a transformer does is filter the output; much like an outward middleware. Transformers also offer the ability of [includes](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/#including-data), allowing you to only show specific data when specifically requested.